# といったら vs. とは - subtle differences?

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax

Question from my JLPT N1 text book:
佐藤さんのセンスの良さ＿＿＿＿＿＿...。本当に感心します。(fill in the blank)
I have a choice of というと、とは、and といったら。
といったら is correct but I can't fathom how とは is not an option as the text says it can be used for subjects that are ひどい、おどろく、すごい (I would think すごい applies here, but perhaps it doesn't?) (text also specifies といったら as for subjects that are 言葉で言い表せないほど最高に～だ）. Any help on the nuances of these two expressions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simply, `～とは!` follows the 終止形 of a verb/adjective (like English "`How + [adjective]!`"), whereas `～といったら!` follows a noun (like English "`What a + [noun]!`").

> - 彼があんなに喜ぶとは！
> - 彼の喜んだ顔といったら！
> - 彼の喜び[よう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33263/5010)といったら！
> - 彼女の絵がこれほどに綺麗だとは！
> - 彼女の絵の綺麗さといったら！
> - 佐藤さんがあんなにセンスがいいとは！
> - 佐藤さんのセンスの良さといったら！

Bonus: [`～といったらない` and `～といったらありはしない`](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-to-ittara-nai/) follow both a noun and an adjective (usually a negative adjective like 恐ろしい). You may be also interested in [～(だ)なんて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34602/5010).